# .Net 2.0: Help troubleshooting a System.AccessViolationException. 100% managed code

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, debugging, access-violation

This is kind of repeated from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444844/can-a-system-accessviolationexception-happen-because-of-faulty-ram), although the objective of my question is completely different now.

I'm getting, now and then, about once a week, only in my development machine, a System.AccessViolationException in a web app I made.

Since my machine is having a few things that don't work quite well (like a blue screen every now and then), I assumed before it might be faulty RAM. After 24 hours running memtest, i'm pretty sure it's not...

So, this is the situation: This is a wep App, VB.Net 2.0, 100% managed code, doesn't use COM, Interop, or anything like that. It's running on a Windows Server 2008 SP2 box.
The only "strange" thing I'm doing is starting 3 threads of my own when the app starts, that do "cron like" stuff inside the appdomain, and also most of the requests this app is handling are handled asynchronously, and many of them are held open without a response for up to 30 seconds. (I'm doing Comet long-polling).

Also, i've been working on this code for about a year now, and it's only started to do this about a month ago.
I can't think of anything major or important that I changed on this whole web app that I changed lately. I've been working almost fully on the Javascript frontend.

---

When the exception happens, I get the typical popup asking me whether I want to debug.
When I do, I see all the ASP.Net threads plus my 3 threads.
My 3 threads are in a call to Sleep(), which is normal. All the other ASP.Net threads have no call stack at all.
In the thread where Visual Studio tells me I got the exception, I don't see anything.

So I don't know for sure where the error happens, or even whether it happens every time in the same place or not.

All I could find as a clue is this in the "Application" event log:

```
Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 7.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e03238, 
faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x00000000, exception code 
0xc0000005, fault offset 0x0000000002358fe8, process id 0x1f4c, application 
start time 0x01ca41395c564ed9.
```

And right after that, another event with this:

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: DefaultDomain    
Process ID: 6632    
Exception: System.AccessViolationException

Message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

StackTrace:    at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

---

I've googled MgdIndicateCompletion , but couldn't find anything really useful...

One thing that HAS changed about a month ago, now that I think of it, is that I moved from Server 2003 x86 to Server 2008 x64 (and thus, IIS6 to IIS7) in my dev machine. Maybe that's the cause, but still, i'm not sure what to make of this...

I mean, this would place the problem completely out of my codebase, right?

---

**UPDATE:** As suggested [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1476904.aspx), turning the App Pool integration to "Classic" seems to fix it. I'm still looking for a decent solution, or at least an explanation, though.

Comment: To eliminate the (unlikely?) possibility that the Server migration is the cause, can you go back in time in your version control and get a version of your app from before the problem started appearing?

Comment: Hmmm, that's a good idea, but being that this is my dev machine, I can't, since I have to keep working on this code...

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your code, I don't know how practical this is, but can you comment-out large swaths of code until the exception no longer happens? If you can, you may be able to use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) approach to find out where the exception occurs.

Comment: The thing is that this problem happens about once every few days. It's absolutely non-reproducible.
Also, this is the dev machine in which i'm working on this project, so commenting out large pieces of code would make it non-functional, and not let me work :-S

Answer (score 0):

Check if antivirus/virus is playing a part. These programs may install faulty hooks to every process.

Comment: I don't have an antivirus in this machine. And I surely hope I don't have a virus either!

Comment: use process explorer to check if there is any extra dll not loaded when you debug on your other machines

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with a "faulting module unknown" type crash. In my case, I have the opposite and it's happening in production on an SBS 2008 machine. I am suspicious it's the version of Windows that is the problem, but I can't be sure. I've narrowed it down by logging (it's a service so I'm able to write to the event log) and I would suggest that's an option for you, possibly within

```
#If DEBUG
    ...
#End If
```

block.

You could also only execute certain portions of code as suggested by JeffH, also using the DEBUG test so you only execute that code in production.

Logging would be my starting point, though, as it gives you clues as to what's just happened when the crash happens. If it's only every few days it happens, then I'd again only write the log file when on your machine to avoid performance problems if the log file gets big!

Good luck...